# B&R Automation Studio - Breakdown of cyclic network communication error

Tags: automation, embedded, robotics, ansi-c, br-automation-studio

I get this error on a B&R controller computer that I use to control a 6-axis stewart platform, but we have not been able to figure out the exact cause with B&R support. This problem comes on occasionally but goes away when I reboot the system and then comes back at random times. Can anyone help me if they have experienced this before?

[image]

Here it is controller link [Controller](https://www.br-automation.com/tr/ueruenler/enduestriyel-pcler/automation-pc-3100/system-units/5apc3100kbu0-000/)

I thought it was related to the tasks I was using exceeding their time, so I monitored how much the controller was using the processor and it maxes out at 60% utilization. I also changed the connection cables thinking that there might be a bug with the powerlink communication but this did not solve the problem. This error does not happen after a certain process, so we cannot get the error by following certain steps in the system. Or we haven't discovered it yet, but for now it seems to us that it happens at random moments.

Comment: Do you know what this cyclical communication is? Is it a field network? If so, it could be a problem with electromagnetic interference.

Comment: The ethernet cable connected to the panel I use is connected to an ethernet switch port and different ethernet cables also enter this port, including the communication of the system connected to our stewart platform. I will check this, so I will try to arrange a cable that is more resistant to electromagnetic noise and protected.